# Cast a javascript object into a model of the controller

Tags: javascript, vb.net, class, object, casting

I created an object in my js file:

```
function Shape(name, color, count) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Color = color;
    this.Count = count;
}

var apples = new Shape('apple', 'green', 5);
```

I want to pass this "class" into the controller via `load`'function, so I wrote:

```
$('#myDiv').load(url, { 'Shape': apples });
```

The `url` is the url of a function in the controller:

```
function GetShape(shape as ShapeModel) as actionResult

End Function
```

While `ShapeModel` is:

```
Class ShapeModel

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Color As String
    Public Property Count As Integer
    Public Property IsHot As Boolean

End Class
```

The function is called by the load function but the parameters of the class are equal to nothing.

I want to convert the class that came in the js file (`Shape`) into the class in the controller(`ShapeModel`) In the function above (`GetShape`).

These classes have the same properties, except one property (`IsHot`).

How can I do it?

I tried to send the class of the js as JSON.stringify and then make a deserialization in the controller from the given string into the class of `ShapeModel`, but the deserializtion failed..

The optimal solution is to send it as a class and not stringify that..

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just so it's said...if you're setting `_IsHot` to some value that has nothing to do with `value`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.. Please assume that the function `func` returns true..

Comment: What i mean is, if `func` isn't dependent on `value`, then `IsHot = true` and `IsHot = false` do exactly the same thing -- and that's broken.

Comment: Ok, I dont think this is the issue of my problem so I edited the topic.. thanks..

Comment: Is the `GetShape` controller method being called and `shape` is null, or is it not being called at all?  Or is something else wrong?  Can't really tell from your question as-is.

Comment: Hi Mark, the shape method is called but the values of the shape in this function are nothing (null)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is in how you are passing the parameters in the jQuery `load` call.  You are wrapping your `Shape` object in another object with a `Shape` property.  Instead, just pass the `Shape` object directly as the data.

```
 $('#myDiv').load(url, apples);
```

I think that MVC only supports binding a single parameter from the body, so you don't need to have something that specifies the parameter name.